# Вызвать функцию из dll

Tags: c++, winapi

Пытаюсь вызвать message box из dll, учебное задание.

```
typedef int (WINAPI* _MessageBoxA)(HWND, LPTSTR, LPTSTR, UINT);
HMODULE user32 = (*LoadLibraryAPointer)("user32.dll");
PDWORD Address = (PDWORD)((LPBYTE)user32 + pIED->AddressOfFunctions);
PDWORD Name = (PDWORD)((LPBYTE)user32 + pIED->AddressOfNames);
PDWORD Ordinal = (PWORD)((LPBYTE)user32 + pIED->AddressOfNameOrdinals);

_LoadLibraryA LoadLibraryAPointer;
_MessageBoxA MessageBoxPointer;

for (int i = 0; i < pIED->AddressOfFunctions; i++)
{
    if (!hashComparatorA(MESSAGE_BOX_HASH, (char*)user32 + Name[i])) 
    {
        MessageBoxPointer = (user32 + Address[Ordinal[i]]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Возникает ошибка

```
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'HMODULE' to '_MessageBoxA'
```

Answer (score 1):

Странные у вас учебные задания. Ошибка возникает из-за того, что тип HMODULE, который определен как указатель на структуру `struct {int unused;}`, несовместим с типом указателя на функцию. Эту ошибку можно убрать приведением типов, но в данном случае это не поможет заставить код работать, так как он выглядит в целом некорректным. Если предположить, что pIED - это указатель на структуру IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY, определенную в winnt.h (которая описывает раздел экспорта PE-файла), то адрес функции должен вычисляться так:

```
MessageBoxPointer = (_MessageBoxA)((char*)user32 + Address[i]);
```

Тип HMODULE нужно привести к указателю на один байт, чтобы адресная арифметика работала как ожидается. Переменная user32 содержит базовый адрес DLL, а Address[i] - относительный адрес функции, поэтому мы их складываем. Ordinal не нужен.